# Maybe move the "Back To Main Site" button out of the "help" dropdown?

Tags: feature-request, design, meta

So I was just going to go back to the main site. I clicked the "help" dropdown and click "Back to Stack Overflow":

[image]

Then I thought, wait, why "Back to Stack Overflow" is under help? I don't need help to go back to Stack Overflow!

The other items are all help-related:

- Tour: It's the place to go when you are a newcomer and want to get help about what Stack Overflow is.
- Help Center: I don't think I need to explain this one.
- What's Meta? - This contains help information about Stack Overflow Meta
- About us - This provides help for those who want to know more about the company
- Business - Here you can learn about hiring developers and advertising.

There is also a "Meta" button in the help drop down on the main site. That is also related to help because when you need support on the site, you post a question on meta.

You see, all these things are related to help **except "Back to Stack Overflow"**.

So I suggest that we move the button to the right of "review", maybe?

EDIT:

Mr Lister in the comments suggests that we ran out of screen space. I understand. But seeing "back to stack overflow" under help is really weird. So maybe we can rename the help dropdown to "more"?

Comment: "**Help!** I'm trapped on Meta!"

Comment: I never noticed that link =/.

Comment: I like this idea - it would also help new users who end up here by accident and then get trapped and don't realize they're in the wrong place.

Comment: @JonasCz I agree with you. I was actually one of those new users!

Comment: I like the idea of having a link back to main. I'd like to be able to navigate back with a single click.

Comment: @Laurel There used to be a direct link, but apparently they ran out of screen space.

Comment: Whenever I am looking to change a community, I use  the tab on the left that is labeled "Stack Exchange."  This is where the main communities are listed, and should stay here.  Not sure why it's in help, but definitely seems   not needed, especially when you can get to the "Main sites" when clicking on the left pulldown.  This help feature only pops up when in a "Meta" or other subforum, and wont appear in the main communities..