# Link back to SO from Meta SO

Tags: discussion, meta, user-interface

Why isn't there a button dedicated to going back to Stack Overflow from Meta Stack Overflow?

I get that the yellow rectangle gets people engaged from SO to MSO but once you've clicked on a link it's not obvious how to come back (from the interface).

I'm aware of the `Stack Exchange Icon > Stack Overflow` path, but I'm curious what's the idea behind not making it obvious (like somewhere in the sidebar).

[image: Screenshot of the Hot Meta Posts box, referred to as the yellow rectangle above.]

Comment: Because you can check out, but you can never leave

Comment: Seriously though, the Stack Exchange icon used to be to the left, which arguably made it a main navigation element. To the right, it's a bit hidden.

Comment: g + m is always available

Comment: @Pekka웃 Yeah I agree it's a bit hidden, hence my question :)

Comment: @KevinB I don't get what you mean

Comment: If you have keyboard navigation enabled, g+m swaps you back and forth between meta and main

Comment: @KevinB I did not know about SE keyboard navigation, thanks for that. Yet it's not my question as I'm interested in the UI/X choice

Comment: I don't think it was a choice, it's simply an unintended consequence. The purpose of the box isn't to get you to meta, it's to draw your attention to things happening around the site. It just so happens that the majority of them revolve around either meta or the blog, but occasionally it's also used for elections. It wouldn't make much sense to link to a random SO question in that box... that's not what it's for.

Comment: Yes I do understand that, yet again it's beside my point. I mean that there is an explicit link between SO and SOM in that one is dedicated to matters of the other. It would have made sense to me to make navigation both-ways obvious

Comment: Partially colorblind, so what yellow rectangle?

Comment: @AndréKool - The 'Hot Meta Posts' box has a light yellow background.

Comment: @AndréKool the `Hot Meta Posts` box

Comment: My guess is it doesn't exist because [this feature request never got any traction](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322552/maybe-move-the-back-to-main-site-button-out-of-the-help-dropdown). Also, this isn't something people complain about a lot. They might put something in the new left nav if a feature request got enough attention for it.

Comment: This has rustled my jimmies for longer than I care to admit but I've never raised the issue.

Comment: there's always the "hot network questions". There's a good chance for a SO question there.

Comment: "what's the idea behind not making it obvious" probably that once you are there, you will know the way back

Comment: See my answer, the button is fairly obvious in my opinion

Comment: related : [Access meta site from main and vice versa from left bar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369418/access-meta-site-from-main-and-vice-versa-from-left-bar)

Comment: Why don't we change the "Featured Meta Post" or "Hot Meta Posts" to something on the main site?

Comment: Cross site duplicate from about six years ago: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115468/how-do-i-navigate-out-of-meta

Comment: Seems like a non-issue. Use a browser which allows you to save bookmarks?

Comment: Not an issue indeed, just a discussion ;)

Comment: I have two pinned tabs; one with meta, one with main. Toggling back and forth is as easy as Ctrl+Tab/Ctrl+Shift+Tab...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I'm reading the HNQ right now and from this page and there's no SO question on the list

Comment: @TylerH too many stackexchange sites :)

Comment: related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368921/the-teams-feed-sits-on-top-of-the-stack-overflow-feed-on-the-homepage-can-we-se

Answer (score 26):

[image]

All you have got to do is click that button, then "Back to Stack Overflow"

You could also do this:

[image]

And if you use Stack Overflow frequently, you can even do this:

[image]

and click on the Stack Overflow icon.

I hope that helped.

Comment: wow. Never saw that one.

Comment: Thanks. I used to go through my profile, and then click on main profile.

Comment: Who thinks of clicking on a help icon for standard navigation options? I don't even get why that link is there in the first place.

Comment: @Marvin Agreed. "Back to Stack Overflow/Return to the Main Site" should probably be a main navigation element, somewhere.

Comment: downvoted 3 times because it's just helpful ????

Comment: I saw this more useful than the other considering it pointed out the help menu link. I swear nobody ever uses it often for a good reason as stated in the comments

Answer (score 15):

Just a general FYI across the SE network, but on any Meta (even Meta.SE) you can click the hamburger menu and get back to the main site for that Meta from there. It's not obvious, but it is there

[image]

Comment: Yeah saw that :)

Comment: Favoring this answer instead because of the helpful red freehand drawn circle...!

Comment: What a nice circle! Upvote.

Comment: same answer that was given to my proposal some days ago... upvoted for the circle even if I don't find that shortcut obivous. My mouse always wander a bit  helplessly before my hand remembers where the link is.

Comment: I don't see why this answer has more upvotes than the answer below. The answer below shows a button that is meant to lead "Back to Stack Overflow"

Comment: "the answer below" is now above... You mean [Shesank's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/369734/6451573)

Comment: nice circle... but it's not a hamburger menu ;)